# Java about @Override

Tags: java, netbeans

So what is the problem with the override i dont get it:

```
@Override
public ProtocolEncoder getEncoder(IoSession session) throws Exception {
    return encoder;
}
@Override
public ProtocolDecoder getDecoder(IoSession session) throws Exception {
    return decoder;
}
```

the error:

```
error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
@Override

error: MaplePacketDecoder is not abstract and does not override abstract method doDecode(IoSession,ByteBuffer,ProtocolDecoderOutput) in CumulativeProtocolDecoder
public class MaplePacketDecoder extends CumulativeProtocolDecoder {

error: method write in interface ProtocolEncoderOutput cannot be applied to given types;
                out.write(IoBuffer.wrap(ret));
  required: ByteBuffer
  found: IoBuffer
  reason: actual argument IoBuffer cannot be converted to ByteBuffer by method invocation conversion
```

Comment: What is your super-type?

Comment: What do you think override means? Because if you know what it means, then the message is extremely clear.

Comment: So how you suggest me to write it>?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to implement `doDecode(IoSession,ByteBuffer,ProtocolDecoderOutput)`.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to override a method in the superclass with different arguments (a different signature.)   The overriding method has to match the signature of the method being overridden (in the parent class).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Comment: Where "match" means having the exact same name and parameter types.  Furthermore, the override will produce a different error if the method's return type is neither the same type as that of the original method nor a subtype of that type.  (As explained in the docs.  +1 for the docs reference.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that either the method names you are trying to override or the argument you are providing is not correct. Also you do not implement the doDecode method from CumulativeProtocolDecoder. If CumulativeProtocolDecoder is an abstract class you should be implementing it.